# How to get conforming protocol from super protocol?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to resolve some types for a simple dependency injection. I'm trying to get the type of the protocol that is conforming to another protocol.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
protocol Module {}
extension Module {
  func register() {
    print(Self)
  }
}

protocol Submodule: Module {}

struct MyType: Submodule {}

print(MyType().register()) // prints "MyType"
```

Is there a way to make it print `Submodule` since it's the one that's conforming to `Module`? I'm trying to get `Module` to know what protocol implemented it.

Comment: try with super.register() you getting better results @TruMan